# AJAX post sending data serialize and image data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a problem in post request in AJAX submitting form serialize and my image data array. How can i do this?

Here is my code:

I want to send this data:

```
var Imagedata = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#addfiles')[0].files, function(i, file) {
  data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

and

```
$("#editProd").serialize()
```

Here is what I did: `data: $("#editProd").serialize()+Imagedata,`

I have this as fullcode :

```
function ProductAjax(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var Imagedata = new FormData();
  jQuery.each(jQuery('#addfiles')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
  });

  $.ajax({         
    url: "{{ route('admin.editProduct') }}",        
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#editProd").serialize()+Imagedata,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').addClass('alert alert-success');
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').find("ul").html('');
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').css('display','block');
        $(".print-error-msg-addcat ul").append('<li class="tick">'+data.success+'</li>');
        $('#frmAddcategory')[0].reset();
        location.reload();
      }else{
        printErrorMsgEditprod(data.error);
      }
    }
  }); 
}
```

Am I doing right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't `data` in `jQuery.each` be `Imagedata`?

Comment: Besides that, you should append you form data in to the `FormData` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code and comments below:

```
function ProductAjax(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData($("#editProd")[0]); //assuming this object is a form element.
  //the FormData object allows a form element to be passed to the constructor. The new instance
  //will have all the form input fields already appended.
  //if not a form element you need to append every input seperately using jQuery.serializeArray

  jQuery.each(jQuery('#addfiles')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file-'+i, file);
  });


  $.ajax({         
    url: "{{ route('admin.editProduct') }}",        
    type: "POST",
    data: formData, //send the formData object containing all the form input.
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').addClass('alert alert-success');
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').find("ul").html('');
        $('.print-error-msg-addcat').css('display','block');
        $(".print-error-msg-addcat ul").append('<li class="tick">'+data.success+'</li>');
        $('#frmAddcategory')[0].reset();
        location.reload();
      }else{
        printErrorMsgEditprod(data.error);
      }
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Remember that it needs to be a form and FormData is only supported in modern browsers. Upvote if this answer helped would be nice.